# NLP - How to add more features?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf

I want to use a sklearn classifier to train a model to classify data entries (yes,no) using a text feature (content), a numerical feature (population) and a categorical feature (location).

[image]

The model below is using only the text data to classify each entry. The text is converted with TF-IDF into a sparse matrix before being imported into the classifier.

Is there a way to add/use also the other features? These features are not in sparse matrix format so not sure how to combine them with the text sparse matrix.

```py
    #import libraries
    import string, re, nltk
    import pandas as pd
    from pandas import Series, DataFrame
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
    from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
    from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

    # read data and remove empty lines
    dataset = pd.read_csv('sample_data.txt',
                           sep='\t',
                           names=['content','location','population','target'])
                           .dropna(how='all')
                           .dropna(subset=['target'])

    df = dataset[1:]

    #reset dataframe index
    df.reset_index(inplace = True)

    #add an extra column which is the length of text
    df['length'] = df['content'].apply(len)

    #create a dataframe that contains only two columns the text and the target class
    df_cont = df.copy()
    df_cont = df_cont.drop(
        ['location','population','length'],axis = 1)

    # function that takes in a string of text, removes all punctuation, stopwords and returns a list of cleaned text

    def text_process(mess):
        # lower case for string
        mess = mess.lower()

        # check characters and removes URLs
       nourl = re.sub(r'http\S+', ' ', mess)

        # check characters and removes punctuation
        nopunc = [char for char in nourl if char not in string.punctuation]

        # join the characters again to form the string and removes numbers
        nopunc = ''.join([i for i in nopunc if not i.isdigit()])

        # remove stopwords
        return [ps.stem(word) for word in nopunc.split() if word not in set(stopwords.words('english'))]

    #split the data in train and test set and train/test the model

    cont_train, cont_test, target_train, target_test = train_test_split(df_cont['content'],df_cont['target'],test_size = 0.2,shuffle = True, random_state = 1)


    pipeline = Pipeline([('bag_of_words',CountVectorizer(analyzer=text_process)),
                         ('tfidf',TfidfTransformer()),
                         ('classifier',MultinomialNB())])

    pipeline.fit(cont_train,target_train)
    predictions = pipeline.predict(cont_test)

    print(classification_report(predictions,target_test))
```

The model is expected to return the following: accuracy, precision, recall ,f1-score

Comment: you can use Neural Network for using both text and numerical data for classifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to use one-hot vectoring for the 'location' feature. 
One-hot vectors for the given data would be,

London - 100

Manchester - 010

Edinburg - 001

Vector length is the number of cities you have in there. Note that each bit here would be a feature.
Categorical data is usually converted to one-hot vectors before feeding to a machine learning algorithm.

Once this is done you can concat the whole row into a 1D array and then feed that to the classifier.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @avin, my question is how to combine the encoding that you described above with the sparse matrix produced by the tf-idf?

Comment: To my knowledge, sklearn needs rows in 1D format. You could try TfidfVectorizer [https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html] to have a 1D vector for each of those sentences. And then one-hot vector the location feature and use `np.concatenate((seq1, seq2,..,seqN))` to concatenate everything to a 1D array?

Comment: Thank you for the help @avin

Answer (score 1):

```
x_tfidf = hstack((x_tfidf , np.array(df['additonal_feature'])[:,None]))  
x_tfidf = x_tfidf.tocsr()
```

The above code is simply adding your additional column to your tf-idf matrix. If your TF-IDF matrix is of dimension M x N, with this step it will add another column of dimension 1 x N, and it will result an array of M+1 x N. So in the end, your model is going to treat the additional column just as an additional nlp token.

The first line results a dense matrix. Thats why I added the second lind which converts it back to Compressed Sparse Row format.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29275526)

Comment: There was no links by the way. I just wrote few lines of codes which does exactly what OP was asking. Just included some details also.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like we can directly encode text as a feature. So you probably need to normalize it. You can pick one of the text rows and set it as a standard. Use TFIDF to calculate the match score between your standard text and the text for each row. You can then encode that percentage as a feature. I realize it is a very roundabout way to encode, but depending on the text you choose as a standard it may work.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your sparse matrix to `numpy array` using `toarray` method.

You will get a vector for each text entry which you can concat with other features.